# two dimensional list with multiple values

Tags: web-app, lists, info-visualisation, structure

We are developing a web applications for e-commerce use when for a list of countries we have different vendors list sort by priority of that vendor.
the maximum lists of country is undefined, it can be one list for all the countries we support or multiple lists with no limit.

**Rules**:

- under a group of countries the user can decided the internal priority
  of vendors.
- country can be only in one list.
- group of vendors can be in different order on each group of countries.

**Flow**:
1. user selects at least one country
2. user selects the vendors from a list of existing vendor, or add a new one
3. user sorts the list of vendors by priority

after a user config it, we want to show him the view of all lists.
the goals of this page is to show the list of countries and under it the list of vendors taking in mind that the user will probably get to this page to look for a specific country.

what is the best presentation for this view? taking inconsideration that the number of lists won't be constant and can varied.

**UPDATE**
This is a new sketch based on the first answer. now, under the assumption that the number of lists is not constant, what do you think about the solution? I'm concerning it will be messy.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd go visually horizontal, and I would give the opportunity to name the country clusters.

For example: I would give users the opportunity to call the group of Norway, Denmark & Finland "Nordic" and have this is cell 1 of the row. Cell 2 of the row is the list of country names, possibly truncated. Cell 3 of the row gives me a list of vendors.

The next question popped up in my mind is: Do we need to compare rows? If the answer is: "Yes, everytime" - you maybe should not hide country names or vendor names. If the answer is "Yes, sometimes" or "No" you could collapse the list items from "Norway, Finland, Denmark" to "3 Countries" and the same for vendors.

I think naming is a powerful recognition tool, so the user does not need to see all containing names all the time.

Comment: we don't need to compare, but we need to keep the list of countries visible so the user can scan when he looks for one specific.  I do like the idea of naming the group, i just don't want to complicate the add flow too much.

Comment: Maybe it is useful to make it possible to filter for all items including a specific country? Like "Show me all clusters that include Sweden". That would make navigation a lot easier.

Comment: you are right!!